# How to disable resizeableActivity without disabling the support of foldable devices

Tags: android, foldable-devices

In the android developers site they say:

> If you set resizeableActivity=false to disable multi-window mode but
> still want to support app continuity, add the following meta-data to
> the manifest of your element:
>
> ```
> <meta-data
>     android:name="android.supports_size_changes" android:value="true" />
> ```
>
> If the value is true and the user attempts to fold or unfold a device,
> the activity will apply any changed configurations in a way that
> supports changes in window sizes.

So I did as they said but the activity isn't automatically resumed when I test it in the emulator.
here is my code:

```
    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:resizeableActivity="false"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:theme="@style/MaterialTheme">
    
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.supports_size_changes" android:value="true" />
     </application>
```

Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Where had you found the snippet in the developer documentation?

Answer (score 1):

We have updated the [developer documentation for multi-window support](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/multi-window-support) to clarify how to control your app's support for preventing your app from running in multi‑window mode.

The primary way of accomplishing this is by setting `resizeableActivity="false"`, but note that there are more refined ways of controlling this behavior by setting minimum size constraints, and that device manufacturers can override these behaviors.